# Using $cordovaClipboard ng-cordova plugin in ionic for iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, clipboard, ngcordova

I am using $cordovaClipboard ng-cordova plugin in my ionic project. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/clipboard/

The plugin works well on Android devices, but when building app for iOS this plugin does not work. Is there something i have missed out on or should consider?

Also, is there a way to run an ionic app on my iOS device or a simulator and at the same time the debug console should also show in terminal?

Comment: What did you try in iOS if you want to run the app in simulator?Did you follow any other procedure?

Comment: @user3182143 I tried testing the app in both simulator and iphone to verify that $cordovaClipboard plugin doesn't work at all.

Comment: Did you try any other code?

Comment: @user3182143 Like I said, all works pretty well in android. I did not change any of my codes after my final android build. All features works fine after building the app for iOS except for the $cordovaClipboard plugin.

Comment: @user3182143 the documentation shows that this is compatible to android, ios and windows http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/clipboard/

Comment: when you run the code what does it show?

Comment: @user3182143 you mean in the console? nothing shows in the console. That's why I am also asking how I can activate logging in the console.

Comment: @user3182143 the application's user interface works as normal. only that the copy to clipboard function is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Debug iOS simulator with Safari](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-i-properly-debug-ios-on-a-simulator/16690)

Try removing the iOS platform and readding it. It will re-add every plugin.

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
```